# Can't aling horizontally items in Angular

Tags: css, angular, nebular

I have 4 item in a div that are show vertically, but I want them align horizontally. I don't know what I'm missing but I'm unable to do it

**This is the HTML**

```
<div class="teachers-box" *ngFor="let user of usuarios">
    <nb-user
      class="teacher-box"
      size="large"
      name="{{ user.name }}"
      color="#cccac8"
      onlyPicture
    >
    </nb-user>
  </div>
```

**This is the .ts where I get the data**

```
usuarios = [
    { name: 'Gabriel A' },
    { name: 'Maximiliano B' },
    { name: 'Chavez C' },
    { name: 'Juan Pablo' },
  ]
```

**This are the scss styles**

```
.teachers-box {
  display: inline-block;
}

.teacher-box {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**I noticed that the item width is taking the whole screen, but I don't know how to remove it**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a div that will wrapper both the `div` and `nb-user`

Something like:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="teachers-box" *ngFor="let user of usuarios">
        <nb-user
          class="teacher-box"
          size="large"
          name="{{ user.name }}"
          color="#cccac8"
          onlyPicture
        >
        </nb-user>
    </div>
 </div>
```

And the style:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

And then you can delete the display `inline-block` from other classes

Answer (score 0):

I would use `flexbox` for this.

Try this:

```
.teachers-box {
  display: flex;
}

.teacher-box {
  width: 25%
}
```

and remove the `.teacher-box` style of `display: inline-block;`

Comment: I tried that but the items are still aling vertically. What I noticed is that each item is taking the whole screen width, as I show in the image. I tried putting max-width but is not working either

Comment: can you show us the generated HTML of your elements ?

Comment: Try adding `.teacher-box { width: 25%; }` but if you go to `codepen`, I am sure you can reproduce it.

Comment: I'm asking the @SirrMaxi to provide the generated HTML of the relevants elements

Comment: @Everton dos Santos Silva give the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `float: left;` to div? As in:

```
.teachers-box {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```